# YiiBooster Select2Row Data/Tag Issues

Tags: php, yii

so I've been trying to get select2Row to work for me forever and I just can't seem to get a hang of it.  What I'm trying to do is provide the user with Tags that list a school/university name, while at the same time storing the value of said tag when I save the form.  I've noticed that I cannot use both data and tags, else my drop down wont populate so that's not an option.  Tags only seem to want text, rather than text and matching values.  Any ideas?

```
<div class="row">
    <?php 
        echo $form->select2Row($model, 'school_id', array(
            'asDropDownList'=>false,
            'options'=>array(
                'tags'=>School::model()->schoolNames,
                //'maximumSelectionSize'=>1,
                'width'=>'297px',
                'tokenSeparators'=>array(','),
            ),
        )); 
    ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'school_id'); ?>
</div>
```

And here is the function for schoolNames

```
public function getSchoolNames()
{
    $schools = array();
    $result = $this->findAllBySQL("SELECT DISTINCT name FROM School");

    foreach($result as $school){
        $schools[] = $school->name;
    }   
    return $schools;
}
```

I've tried using this instead, but the tags won't populate

```
public function getSchools()
{
    $query = "SELECT id,name FROM School";
    $results = $this->findAllBySQL($query);

    return CHtml::listData($results, 'id', 'name');
}
```

So at the moment, select2Row is generating a list of tags using getSchoolNames() and that all works fine, except once you submit the form using those tags you'll get this
`Please fix the following input errors:
School must be an integer.`

Sorry for all the trouble, I'm still a little new to this. I'm sure the answer is probably right in front of me.  Thanks either way =)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
echo $form1->select2Row($model, 'school_id', array(
   'data' => School::model()->schoolNames,
   'multiple' => 'multiple',
   'options' => array(
       "width" => '70%',
   ),
));
```